# performing authenticated scan for xss using selenium and xsstrike tool

Tags: xss, cookies, automated-testing

I'm automating XSS security test, I automated XSS reflected and stored, now for automating XSS dom I'm required to use XSSStrike tool (https://github.com/s0md3v/XSStrike/wiki/Usage). 
Im using Selenium to automated the business logic (login) get cookies and store cookies in json and txt file. however when I provide the cookies for the tool

```
python xsstrike.py -u https://test.com/ --headers  "cookie:C:\Users\Desktop\cookies\cookie.json" --crawl --blind --params --file-log-level INFO --log-file log
```

I don't see if the tool used the cookies or not, i used Wireshark to filter to see if the tool used the cookies but it doesn't capture it. also from the log, there is nothing about using cookies.

is there a way to verify if the tool used the cookies and performed an authenticated xss scan?
also I'm not sure which cookies to provide.

my script to store the cookies

```
 def login(self,url):
        driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'C:\Users\Desktop\geckodriver.exe')
        cookiepath = "C:/Users/Desktop/cookies/cookie.txt"
        cookiepath2 = "C:/Users/Desktop/cookies/cookie.json"
        driver.get(url)
        username = driver.find_element_by_id("Username")
        password = driver.find_element_by_id("password")
        username.send_keys("test")
        password.send_keys("testtest")
        driver.find_element_by_id("btnLogin").click()
        self.save_cookie(driver,cookiepath) # store cookies as txt file
        self.save_cookies(driver,cookiepath2) # store cookies as json
        elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*")
        source_code = elem.get_attribute("outerHTML")
        driver.close()
        return source_code
```